# Change the file type when downloading Is Asp.Net Core 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, getscript

I have two files with `js extension` that need to be downloaded one after the other in one view. The problem that has  is that I in Debug mode, after I publish from the desired file and put it in `IIS`, the extension type of the second file is `xml`. and it gives an error.

**The following code works correctly in Debug mode and loads the desired js**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.$(document).ready(function() {

            window.$.getScript("/***/script-controller.js")
                .done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {

                    window.$('#layoutMain').html(ShowLoading());

                    window.$.getScript("/***/Home.js")
                            .done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {

                            })
                            .fail(function() {

                            });

                })
                .fail(function() {

                });


        })
    </script>
}
```

**The following image is in Debug mode**

[image]
**The image below when published and placed in IIS**

[image]

Comment: Do you see  their size in each case? They are different. The XML one in my assumption contains an error message based on size.

Comment: It's a 404 on IIS, so I guess the upload didn't go well? If there is no file to download, the incorrect content type is the less of your problems :).